# Facet on multi value field combined with sum of other field

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have a similar solr scheme like this:

```
<doc>
    <str name="count">5</str>
    <arr name="tag_id">
        <str>1</str>
        <str>2</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="count">2</str>
    <arr name="tag_id">
        <str>2</str>
        <str>3</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

And as a result I am looking for the facets on tag_id combined with the sum of count like:

tag_id: sum
1: 5
2: 7
3: 2

Is there an easy solution with this? I stumpled upon function queries, but I am not sure if this is solvable with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check for Solr [Pivots](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets)

Solr Pivot should be able to provide hierarchical facets, which you can use as `facet.pivot = tag_id,count`.

You should get back results as

```
tag_id 1
    count 5
tag id 2
    count 2
    count 5
tag id 3
    count 2
```

You can do the count consolidation on the client side.

Comment: Ah nice thanks! Unfortunately Pivots is only available in Solr 4.0. We currently use Solr 3.5, so we should consider an upgrade, but it would be nice if there is a way without client side processing.

Comment: there is no out of the box way to perform this ... you can check for solr pivot patch if available for 3.5